# Set and get value of session in angular js meteor

Tags: angularjs, session, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm creating a multipage application in angular js meteor.I'm using angular-ui router to route through different pages.I wanted to know how can I check if session exists or not.If it exists then open the template else do nothing.

```
     angular.module('myapp').config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $stateProvider
        .state('List', {
            url: '/list',
            template: '<list></list>'
        })

        .state('Entry', {
            url: '/Entry',
            template: '<entry></entry>'
        })
        .state('modal', {
            url: '/modal',
            template: '<modal></modal>'
        })
        .state('loginList',{
         url:'/loginlist',
         template:'<login-list></login-list>'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/404");
});
```

How can I get session before opening particular template?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onEnter` feature for that purpose.

[you can read more there](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)

or you can use `$stateChangeStart` event to check this for each route

[more info here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)